# Is it possible to have a dynamic ref in react js?

Tags: reactjs, ref

Is it possible to have a dynamic ref in react js.

I want to assign a dynamic value in **ref** of span.

I dont have any idea how to call the dynamic ref.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    hide = () =>{
        const span = this.refs.ref-1; // I dont have any idea how to call the dynamic ref here.
        span.className = "hidden";
    }

    table = () =>{   
        //postD is something axios request;

        const tableDetail = Object.keys(postD).map((i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <h2>{ postD[i].title }</h2>
                    <p>{ postD[i].content }</p> 

                    <span ref={"ref-"+postD[i].id} id="test">The Quick Brown Fox.</span> --> the ref is like ref="ref-1" and ref="ref-2" and ref="ref-3" so on.. it is dynamic 
                    <button onClick={() => this.hide()} >Like</button>
                </div>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>  
                <h2>Table</h2>
                {this.table()}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need ref for each span? maybe the requirement can be achieved by other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By updating below two methods you will get the solutions.

Pass `id` in `hide` method.

```
  table = () => {
    const tableDetail = Object.keys(postD).map((i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <h2>{postD[i].title}</h2>
        <p>{postD[i].content}</p>
        <span ref={`ref-${postD[i].id}`} id={`test-${postD[i].id}`}>The Quick Brown Fox.</span>
        <button onClick={() => this.hide(postD[i].id)} >Like</button>
      </div>
    ));
  }
```

Use same `id` to get the ref.

```
hide = (id) => {
  const span = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[`ref-${id}`]);
  span.className = "hidden";
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: @larp If it's working fine for you then accept this answer so it will helpful to other developers as well.

Comment: It is not adding "hidden" in the className.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` to add class name.

Comment: Which version of react are you using in your project?

Comment: my bad, I put **ClassName**, please change also your answer to **className**. it now working thanks! :)

Comment: Ohh yes. You are right. I have updated my answer. Can you please accept it so it will help full to other developer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet. I have updated your class. Just pass "id" to the hide method.

```
    class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        hide = (id) => {
            const span = this.refs[`ref-${id}`]; 
            span.ClassName = "hidden";
        }

        table = () => {       
            const tableDetail = Object.keys(postD).map((i) => (
                    <div key={postD[i].id}>
                        <h2>{postD[i].title }</h2>
                        <p>{postD[i].content }</p> 
                        <span ref={`ref-${postD[i].id}`} id={`${postD[i].id}`}>The Quick Brown Fox.</span>
                        <button onClick={() => this.hide(postD[i].id)} >Like</button>
                    </div>
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <>  
                    <h2>Table</h2>
                    {this.table()}
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```